# How to make an text float next to an image in HTML/CSS?

Tags: html, css

I started learning a bit of HTML yesterday and today I figured out how to work with CSS as well. But I am facing a couple of troubles..
At first I wanted to make a simple business site providing the author names and his stuff etc
Anyway my question is how to make a text float next to an image in HTML/CSS?

```
h2.title {
  width: 120px;
  height: 130px;
  background: url('nopic.png') no-repeat;
  background-size: 170px 130px;
  background-position: 50% 50%;
  background-color: #EEE;
  box-shadow: 0 0 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, .8);
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, .8);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, .8);
  position: left;
}
```

-

```
<div id="header">
  <h1>My header</h1>
  <h2 class="Title">Full Name, Age and Nationality</h2>
</div>
```

This is what it outputs:

[image]

This is how it should be:

[image]

P.S Other methods are accepted, But just to keep the shape of the image border right etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there is no `position:left`.

here is a possible solution for you using your actual code with `background`:

```css
#header div {
  width: 120px;
  height: 130px;
  background: url('http://lorempixel.com/120/130') no-repeat;
  background-size: 170px 130px;
  background-position: 50% 50%;
  background-color: #EEE;
  box-shadow: 0 0 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, .8);
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, .8);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, .8);
  float: left;
  margin:0 10px 0 0
}
```

```html
<div id="header">
  <h1>My header</h1>
  <div></div>
  <h2>Full Name, Age and Nationality</h2>
</div>
```

another solution with tag `img` instead of `background`

```css
#header div {
  width: 120px;
  height: 130px;
  background-color: #EEE;
  box-shadow: 0 0 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, .8);
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, .8);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, .8);
  float: left;
  margin:0 10px 0 0
}
```

```html
<div id="header">
  <h1>My header</h1>
  <div><img src="http://lorempixel.com/120/130" /></div>
  <h2>Full Name, Age and Nationality</h2>
</div>
```

Comment: Your code doesn't work sadly, It actually do a whole another thing which I wanted to do at first but I appreciate your help anyways.
It centers the details text under the 'My header' text and merge the image with the div below the header div and shows navigations text next to it(Sorry if it wasn't the full code I posted but if it wasn't clear enough tell me so I can update the post)

Answer (score 0):

The way I would do this is using the css `:after` selector. First wrap the image in a div tag:

```
<div id='image'>
    <img  src="https://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo11w.png"/>
</div>
```

Then in the css do something like this:

```
#image img {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
}
#image:after {
    position:absolute; 
    width: 50px; /* this makes it so that the text wraps*/
    content: "name age nationality";
}
```

Information on the after selector can be found [here](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_after.asp).

Comment: I am not allowed to vote yet, By the way your code works but I didn't understand it, now it is pretty clear thanks.
Else, Why the image is centered?

Answer (score 0):

If your question is simply "How do I float an image left or right of some text?" then all you have to do is use CSS `float` like this:

```css
img {
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<img src="https://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo11w.png" width="30%" />
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
```

Comment: Please beware, this will left align and add wrap to all images on the page! If you choose this method, do add classes to your images.

Answer (score 0):

Add `align="left"` to your image.

Welcome to the world of web development!

```html
<div id='image'>
        <img src="https://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo11w.png" width="100px" height="100px" style="float: left" />
    </div>
    <div>Some Text
        <br />That is
        <br />Left Aligned</div>
```

Comment: HTML `align` is deprecated therefore shouldn't be advised to use.

Comment: Whoops... Haven't used align in quite some time! Missed it being deprecated! Updated above.

Answer (score 0):

You can also have table like

```
<div id='image'>
    <img src="https://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo11w.png" align="left" width="100px" height="100px" padding="15px" />
</div>
<div>
<table>
<tr>
<th>Full Name</th><td>Joe Akim</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<th>Age</th><td>23years old</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<th>Nationality</th><td>American</td>
</tr>
</div>
```